# ttributeError: type object '' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django , and totally confused about the error I face.
i am trying to create a rest api and apply django filtering option to it.

here is my view code.

```
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
class op_listView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = op_Serializer
    queryset = Op.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter, SearchFilter)
    filter_fields=('website', 'organization__name', 'sectors__name','countries__name')
```

my model

```
class Op(models.Model):
    website = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    op_link = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    close_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    checksum = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    relevancy = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    mark_relevant = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=105)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    read_status = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def attachments(self):
        return self.attachments_set.all()

    @property
    def countries(self):
        return self.country_set.all()

    @property
    def sectors(self):
        return self.sector_set.all()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "op"
```

my serializer

```
class op_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    attachments = attachments_Serializer(many=True , required=False)
    countries = country_Serializer(many=True , required=False)
    sectors = sector_Serializer(many=True , required=False)

    class Meta :
        model = Op
        fields = ['id', 'website', 'op_link', 'title', 'description' , 'organization' , 'close_date' ,
                  'created_at', 'relevancy', 'published_date', 'language' , 'status' , 'read_status' ,
                  'attachments', 'countries', 'sectors']
        depth = 2
```

urls

```
from . import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('op-filter', views.op_listView, basename='op-filter')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

my code does not work and says

```
  extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: type object 'op_listView' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions
```

can anyone help me with the solution. you help is much appreciated.

Comment: `ListAPIView` can't be used with `router`s and hence you should wire-up the view using *normal `path()`* function

Answer (score 0):

for this to work, use path, instead of url or register, i used path and it works fine,
Forinstance use,
path('api/register',RegisterAPI , 'register'),

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by changing my viewset from this:

```py
class TestRunGetView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """ View to get details of one test job run. """
    permission_classes = [HasAPIKey | IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = TestRun.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestRunSerializer
```

To this:

```py
class TestRunGetView(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                     viewsets.mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    """ View to get details of one test job run. """
    permission_classes = [HasAPIKey | IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = TestRun.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestRunSerializer
```

And also doing this in `urls.py`:

```py
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from myapp.views import TestRunGetView

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/testrun', TestRunGetView, basename='testrun')
```