# Django REST get query with symmetric fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The idea is that, given two hashes, I should return the comparison number between them. These two hashes uniquely identify a database entry and the comparison is symmetric. I have the following model:

`models.py`

```py
class Comparison(models.Model):
    result = models.FloatField()
    hash1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hash2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        constraints=[
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['hash1','hash2'], name='compared')
        ]
```

`serializers.py`

```py
class ComparisonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comparison
        # exclude = ['']
        fields = '__all__'
```

`views.py`

```py
class ComparisonView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  
    serializer_class = ComparisonSerializer   
    queryset = Comparison.objects.all()  
    def get_queryset(self):
        h1 = self.request.query_params.get("hash1")
        h2 = self.request.query_params.get("hash2")
        try:
            return self.queryset.filter(hash1=h1, hash2=h2)
        except Comparison.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                return self.queryset.filter(hash1=h2, hash2=h1)
            except Comparison.DoesNotExist:
                return None
```

Which works, but is clunky since the overridden method `get_queryset` tries searching for the data one way around and if it doesn't find anything, tries the other direction. This is necessary since I only store one entry per comparison in order to save space, for instance, `hash1 = ab5d..., hash2= ef3h..., result=0.4` and not `hash1 = ef3h..., hash2= ab5d..., result=0.4`. Is there any way to make a query that is more "symmetric"?

Finally, one other small annoyance is that ideally I want to return a single object, while currently `filter` returns a list containing a single object for a unique hash pair. Replacing `filter` with `get` yields a not iterable error (documentation for REST always uses filter as far as I could tell), so I am not sure how to use the get functionality of base Django here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `QuerySet` that renders with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class ComparisonView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  
    serializer_class = ComparisonSerializer   
    queryset = Comparison.objects.all()  
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        h1 = self.request.query_params.get('hash1')
        h2 = self.request.query_params.get('hash2')
        return self.queryset.filter(
            Q(hash1=h1, hash2=h2) |
            Q(hash1=h2, hash2=h1)
        )
```

> Finally, one other small annoyance is that ideally I want to return a single object, while currently filter returns a list containing a single object for a unique hash pair.

This is because you use the `list` function of the `ModelViewSet`. The viewset will retrieve an object if you specify a primary key (of the `Comparison`).

What you can do is working with a [**`RetrieveAPIView`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview), and override the [**`.get_object()`** method [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_objectself):

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView

class ComparisonView(RetrieveAPIView):  
    serializer_class = ComparisonSerializer   
    queryset = Comparison.objects.all()  
    
    def get_object(self):
        h1 = self.request.query_params.get("hash1")
        h2 = self.request.query_params.get("hash2")
        return get_object_or_404(
            self.queryset,
            Q(hash1=h1, hash2=h2) |
            Q(hash1=h2, hash2=h1)
        )
```

You might want to add an extra constraint that `hash1` is always less than or equal to `hash2`, this thus prevent retrieving two items, since it might be possible that there exists a `Comparison` for `hash1=h1` and `hash2=h2`; and one for `hash1=h2` and `hash2=h1`. You can add a `CheckConstraint` with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F

class Comparison(models.Model):
    result = models.FloatField()
    hash1 = models.CharField(max_lModelViewSetength=100)
    hash2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        constraints=[
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['hash1','hash2'], name='compared'),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=Q(hash1__lte=F('hash2')), name='symmetry')
        ]
```

In that case the create logic should determine which of the two hashes is the smallest. It also means that you can query simply by first ordering `h1` and `h2` with:

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView

class ComparisonView(RetrieveAPIView):  
    serializer_class = ComparisonSerializer   
    queryset = Comparison.objects.all()  
    
    def get_object(self):
        h1 = self.request.query_params.get('hash1')
        h2 = self.request.query_params.get('hash2')
        if h1 is not None and h2 is not None:
            h1, h2 = sorted((h1, h2))
        return get_object_or_404(
            self.queryset, hash1=h1, hash2=h2
        )
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! As an additional note for noobs like me, `RetrieveAPIView` cannot be used with routers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387889/ttributeerror-type-object-has-no-attribute-get-extra-actions